# Tutorials on writing custom Django widgets?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I'm trying to modify the Django Admin interface. I need a custom type of textbox that does some pre/post processing on the text. If I understand correctly, a custom widget is the way to go about this.

Any good tutorials on how to write custom widgets for Django?

Comment: Sure I've seen it in the docs somewhere, but now can't find it.

Comment: If the pre/post processing effects the textbox, is there a reason you can't define it at the model level ?  Rather than at the widget level ... this way the processing would happen regardless of the input method (admin, site, shell, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this reference for the admin site:
http://www.slideshare.net/lincolnloop/customizing-the-django-admin

Answer (score 6):

I found this: http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2008/03/28/overriding-a-single-field-in-the-django-admin-using-newforms-admin

Comment: This answered it for me. It's worth noting it's an old post, "newforms" is now just "forms". There's also a typo: first arg to super should be "VehicleAdmin" not "ArticleOptions" as it is in the article.